# Value of the label is modified, but not changed in the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label

Well, I have two forms here and I want to pass the data from the secondary form (AddUserForm) to the primary (Form1). My problem is that is not working.
For exemple, I put in Form1 the following:

```
AddUserForm secondaryform = new AddUserForm();
secondaryform.label1.Text = "I was created in AddUserForm and will change my text here in Form1!";
```

This works. I can use this to change the value and text of the label of AddUserForm in the Form1, but not vice-versa.
Now see this, using the same method in the secondary form:

```
Form1 primaryform = new Form1();
primaryform.label1.Text = "I was created in Form1 and will change my text here in AddUserForm!";
```

This don't work! The label text does not change!
I've used a MessageBox to show me the content of the label, and showed me the indicated text (I was created in Form1 and will change my text here in AddUserForm!)
By this way I can conclude that the value of the label is changed but the text in form stay the same!
Why this don't work if I add the reference in secondary form? Can anyone help? I really need to solve this! Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Per my comments in your previous question relating to this issue, you need to post a concise-but-complete code example that reliably demonstrates the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm guessing you are creating *new* instances of the form when you probably want to reference the existing ones.  Your code examples don't compile, by the way.

Comment: @LarsTech I've updated the question. I made a mistake.

Comment: @PeterDuniho this is a different issue. I've found the method do reference elements, but I don't know why this don't work if I want to modify the data of primary form from the secondary.

Comment: Yes, I know you've found the method to reference elements. I'm the one who _answered_ your question. But you still need to post a good code example if you want help with your new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows that you are creating a new instance of `Form1` when trying to set its `label1.Text` instead of referencing the existing `Form1`. You need a variable in your `AddUserForm` that can hold a reference to a `Form1`.

You should add something like the following to your AddUserForm:

```
public Form1 MyForm1;
```

Then, change the first code block to (assuming your `Form1` is what's creating the `AddUserForm`)

```
AddUserForm secondaryform = new AddUserForm();
secondaryform.MyForm1 = this;
secondaryform.label1.Text = "Text";
```

And then change your second code block to:

```
MyForm1.label1.Text = "Text";
```

Comment: Problem solved! I really think that your answer will help too many guys that are facing this problem! Thank you man, a great hug! :)